# Why can't I MOV a 64 bit value to a 64-bit register?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, nasm

I have a question when it compiles assembly code (as previously thought x64) and tries to load the following data onto the stack:

```
mov rax, "AAAAAAAAA"; flax == 9
push rax
```

gets the message:

```
warning: character constant too long [-w + other]
```

I know it's only a warning, but I thought it operates on 64-bit registers, which is also indicated by their name.

The system is 64 bit Debian (I think).
The program also compiles as a 64 bit binary file:

```
nasm - f elf64
```

Can anyone explain to me, or at least give me some keywords, how to delve into the topic :)

Comment: You have 9As, 8*9 > 64

Comment: ehh...ok so i need to remember the basics of hexadecimal. Sorry, I assumed each character was 4 bits. topic is closed

Comment: You arent writing hexadecimal here? At least as far as I can tell

Comment: 0xAAAAAAAAA would be 9*4 is 36 bits, which would fit.

Comment: What you wrote attempts to load a value that is 9 copies of the ASCII character A, so its numerical value is `0x414141414141414141`.  Did you perhaps mean `mov rax, 0xAAAAAAAAA` instead?  That would work.

Comment: But "AAAAAAAAA" Is just a 9 byte long string

Comment: @NateEldredge - I was curious what would happen if I put more than 64 bits on the stack

Answer (score 5):

If you look closely:

```
mov rax, “AAAAAAAAA”; flax == 9
```

The string actually contains 9 `'A'`s. Every character is 1 byte, so 8 bits. That means, in a 64-bit register you can only have 8 of them because 8 chars * 8 bits/char = 64 bits.

To write hex constants, use `mov rax, 0xAAAAAAAAA` like in C.  Single or double quotes in NASM give you (multiple) ASCII characters as a little-endian integer value taking the ASCII characters in source order.

Comment: Thank you, I am ashamed for this question ... I made wrong assumptions